# Excel Auto-apply filter or not

Tags: excel

I have three versions of Excel -- newest Excel for PC, Mac, and Excel Online. It seems that Excel-Mac does auto-apply when doing a filter but Excel-PC and Excel-only requires selecting an Apply/OK button. For example:

[image]

Is this a setting that can be modified? If not, why does the PC/Online version not do auto-filtering but the Mac version does?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What is auto-apply?

Comment: @BigBen there's the OK/Cancel button at the bottom right of the filter panel on the left. In other words, if I del-select "March" it will not automatically apply that filter -- I would then have to click the "OK" button for it to apply.